# Calculated datetime column returns string;# in search index

Tags: search, search-results, calculated-column, metadata

We have a calculated column, that results in a date. It's output type is set to DateTime - Date only. When we run the search indexer, it shows up in "crawled properties" as a Text-column, and in the display (in search results) it has a string;# in front of the date-value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Values for [SPFieldCalculated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcalculated.aspx) field are stored in the following format:

> FieldType;#FieldValue

For calculated column with DateTime [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype.aspx) field has the following format:

> "datetime;#DateValue"

When field value is rendered ([GetFieldValueAsHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalueashtml%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [GetFieldValueAsText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalueastext%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) its value is extracted, but it is displayed as raw value when used in search results (crawled property).

Comment: Ok, I get that one, but when the column is defined as DateTime/DateOnly in the field definition, and the formula returns a date, but the search indexer returns it as "string;#DateValue", I would say there is a problem?

Comment: This is a nice explanation but it doesn't solve the issue of removing the "string;#" or "datetime;#" from the search result.  Is this at all possible using a calculated column?

Comment: Thanks. I suspect the only option here would be to customize search results, I.e. to modify column formatting via xsl..